# Find path between multiple nodes by property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I am trying to find all the nodes between a node of my choosing and a property, called Stop:true. Note: I would like for it to include the stop node.

So If I have a set of nodes like this:

```
(id:1,Stop:false)-(id:2,Stop:false)-(id:3,Stop:false)-(id:4,Stop:false)-
(id:5,Stop:false)-(id:6,Stop:True)-(id:7,Stop:false)-(id:8,Stop:false)
```

It would return 
    (id:1,Stop:false)-(id:2,Stop:false)-(id:3,Stop:false)-(id:4,Stop:false)-
    (id:5,Stop:false)-(id:6,Stop:True)

So far I have

```
MATCH p=(a:Node{id:1})-[*]-(b:Node)
WHERE NOT b.Stop = true
RETURN p
```

But this query still returns nodes that are connected to the stop node. How do I make it show ALL the nodes up to the stop node?

Comment: Can you clarify what your trying to do? Some sample data and expected results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should return every path from your chosen node to a Stop node (i.e.., a node that has a `Stop` value of `true`). If your DB has paths with multiple Stop nodes, then this query would return a path to each Stop node (meaning that some of the returned paths could contain multiple Stop nodes).

```
MATCH p=(a:Node{id:6})-[*]-(b:Node {Stop: true})
RETURN p;
```

However, if you only want paths that have a single Stop node (at the end), then this query should work:

```
MATCH p=(a:Node{id:6})-[*]-(b:Node {Stop: true})
WHERE NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE n.Stop)
RETURN p;
```

[NOTE]

Variable-length path patterns (like `()-[*]-()`) have exponential time and space complexity. If the average degree of a node is X, then traversing a variable-length path to depth Y imposes a complexity of O(X^Y). You would normally need to specify a reasonable upper bound on variable-length patterns (e.g., `()-[*..5]-()`) to avoid running out of memory or having the query take seemingly forever to run. The upper bound you specify would depend on the nature of your query and your actual data characteristics.

Comment: What is the [1..-1] mean?

Comment: It takes the list of nodes (returned by `NODES(p)`) and returns a new list consisting of the 2nd through next-to-last elements. See [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-lists-general) for more details.

Comment: So the top query isn't working for me, the spinner on the webgui keeps spinning indefinitely even when I checked for connections before hand. Would it make any difference if property on the end node was a string?

Comment: See the NOTE that I added to my answer. You need to specify a reasonable upper bound on your variable-length query.